# The benefit of the shared key generated from ECDH key exchange protocol

Tags: encryption, elliptic-curves, diffie-hellman

What the benefit of the shared key that generated from ECDH key exchange protocol?
Can I use it to encrypt the message or encrypt the public key of asymmetric encryption?

Answer (score 0):

In principle your could use the derived secret for encryption. But this has several disadvantages. It may leak information about the involved keys and is vulnerable by man-in-the-middle attacks.

A common scheme is to use the derived shared secret to seed a [key derivation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) to derive stronger keys and get better security properties (forward secrecy, ...)

Comment: How does the use of a key derivation function protect you from man-in-the-middle attacks?  If you bring MITM up, you might want to mention how to defend against it...